# Filter records based on groups [Odoo]

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I am trying to filter the records based on their group id. I have written a domain filter in `menu action` like this

```
[('pending_approver','in',[g.id for g in user.groups_id])]
```

`pending_approver` is a `Many2one` field with `res.groups`

Have a look on this for more clarification.

```
def _default_approver(self):
    obj = self.env['approval_heirarchy.approval_rules'].search([('id', '=', 1)], limit=1)
    if obj.x_approver_ids:
        val = obj.x_approver_ids[0].x_user_ids
        return obj.x_approver_ids[0].x_user_ids.id

pending_approver = fields.Many2one('res.groups', string="Pending Approver", readonly=True,default=_default_approver)
```

Whenever run the application **prompt an Odoo Client Error**:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected "]", got "(name)"
```

I've searched a lot but didn't find any solution.
Any help will be a great regard for me. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you use `[('pending_approver','in',user.groups_id.ids)]`

Comment: If you show full stack trace is better and where did you put the domain in the action?

Answer (score 2):

```
if self.user_has_groups('sales_team.group_sale_manager') is True:
    code part...
```

this code may help you.....any queries please free to ask